# Explanation of Lemma 2.34 in Hatcher's ''Algebraic Topology"?

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

In this proof of the Lemma 2.34 of  [*Algebraic Topology*](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch2.pdf) I don't understand 2 things. 
[image]

$(1)$ Hatcher defines $Y_i:=T\cup (X\times[i,\infty])$, then I think that it's obvius the fact that $Y_i$ deformation retracts onto $Y_{i+1}$, since $[i,\infty]$ deformation retracts onto $[i+1,\infty]$.

$(2)$ With the retractions of $Y_i$ in $Y_{i+1}$ how I can obtain a deformation retract of $X\times [0,\infty)$ onto $T$?

Comment: I've edited your title a bit, since it doesn't seem like you're actually claiming that something is wrong with Hatcher's proof; you're asking for clarification on two points. Feel free to rollback the edit if you see fit.

Comment: Thanks :) Now...Can you help me with the problem? I'm desperate! xD

Answer (score 0):

Concerning (1), we cannot just expect a deformation retraction of $X\times \lbrack i,\infty )$ to $X\times \lbrack i+1,\infty )$ to extend to a deformation retraction of the larger space $T\cup X\times\lbrack i,\infty )$. For instance, $S^1$ is the union of its northern and southern (closed) hemispheres. Both hemispheres deformation retract to a point, but there is no deformation retraction of $T$ which, e.g., is the identity on the southern hemisphere while deforming the northern hemisphere to a point.

As for (2), the point is to compress each $Y_i$ in increasingly short time intervals. The resulting homotopy is well-defined and continuous, essentially due to the "pasting lemma" from elementary point-set topology; the intervals $\lbrack 1 - 1/2^i, 1 - 1/2^{i+1}\rbrack$ form a closed cover of the unit interval and the partial homotopies agree on the intersections $\lbrace 1/2^i\rbrace$ by construction. This allows us to eventually compress every $Y_i$ (this is no weirder than Achilles catching up to the turtle).